flutter build tabbar or segmented control with custom shape
I'm currently developing an app using Flutter and I'm in need of assistance to create a custom segmented control or tab bar. I am attaching an image here that precisely illustrates what I need to build.
I want to ensure that the implementation is done professionally. Could someone help me achieve this?
I want out put like this
I tried many segmented control plugins and also used defalut tabbar but not able to achive this.
Suggestions or answers needed
Thanks in advance
